# Roblox How Can I Transfer the Information I Get from the TextBox to the Value

Tags: lua, roblox

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRr5b.png) I am trying to make a smart board in the game. When I read the Qr CODE it gives me a code. If I type and confirm in the text box, the smartboard opens. I've been looking for this for hours but can't find it. Can you help me (I'm writing from a bad translation in English) in summary: when I write the code, the smartboard should turn on

I expect: I was expecting it to work when I wrote the code on the smart board and started controlling it.
I tried: fireworks and script if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi! As you're a new user, you should read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks in advance :)